# Getting No such file or Directory on some Android versions only

Tags: android

I am very much confused with my code it is because of the FileOutputStream seems to find a file on Android 8.0 and 5.0. However, on other Android versions such as Android 4.0, 6.0, 7.0, it gives me a No such file or directory (java.io.FileNotFoundException).

This is my block of code:

```
try{

            File appFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Constants.DEFAULT_FOLDER);
            if (!appFolder.exists()){
                appFolder.mkdir();
            }

            File imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Constants.DEFAULT_FOLDER + "/" +  mShortName);

            if (!imageFile.exists()){

                URL url = new URL(mImageUrl);

                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            }
            Log.i("error", "" + imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            share(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            mRespHandler.sendEmptyMessage(Constants.RESPONSE_SET_WALLPAPER_ERROR);
        }
```

So, I am receiving the FileNotFoundException on this line: `FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);`

I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` on my Manifest.

What can be the problem with this one?

Comment: `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is a dangerous permission. Are you requesting it at runtime?

Comment: It is in the manifest file

Comment: Since Marshmallow, you have to request it at runtime, as well, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23+.

Answer (score 0):

Google [documenation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) states you can call `Environment.getExternalStorageState` to make sure the external storage is available.